# Return documents grouped by date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In MySQL I would use an aggregate function to get records grouped by date:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DATE(created_at) creation FROM records GROUP BY creation;

+-----------+------------+
| COUNT(id) | creation   |
+-----------+------------+
|        10 | 2015-04-22 |
+-----------+------------+
|        5  | 2015-11-22 |
+-----------+------------+
```

How could I achieve the same thing in MongoDB, given that I have an id and created_at column as well:

```
db.contacts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55394a8c6d616386e3020000"), "name" : "sfdsf fddfgfdg", "email" : "gdfg@fdgij.com", "fax" : "", "birth_date" : null, "phone" : "453454564", "phone_2" : "", "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-04-23T19:39:56.966Z"), "created_at" : ISODate("2015-04-23T19:39:56.966Z") }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate using the [`$group` aggregation command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group). To group by date rather than by datetime, you can use operators to extract [year](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/#exp._S_year), [month](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month) and [day](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/#exp._S_dayOfMonth):

```
[
  {
    "$group" : {
       "_id" : { month: { $month: "$date" }, 
                 day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" }, 
                 year: { $year: "$date" } },
       "count" : { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) for this.

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$created_at", count: {$sum: 1}}}
]);
```